# Force image download from S3 with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, download

I'm trying to download images with a link that routes me to this method:

```
    $image = $st->getFullPathWithImage(null, $type, true, true);

    if ($image) {
        $content_type = 'image/jpeg';

        $basename = basename($image);

        Download::add($st->id);

        return Response::download($image, $basename, array('Content-Type: ' . $content_type));
    }
```

If I try and debug what I have in **$image** I get the correct URL from S3, however the method fails stating that:

```
The file "path_to_my_bucket/uploads/14424179653mYJLut2zVEnyR30YQEm.jpg" does not exist
```

I'm guessing that this is due to something I must set on S3/AWS, but I'm clueless to what it is, and how I can bind it to Laravel's Response::download(). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering for someone with the same issue.

Turns out S3 had nothing to do with the issue. Instead of using Laravel's Response::download(), I switched for manual, raw php header setting and things do work. I'm not sure why the regular Laravel solution returned a 404, but I needed an easy and quick fix and this is the best I could find.

So, instead of returning Response::download(), do this:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($image));
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

return readfile($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also return a redirect to the image URL

```
return response()->redirectTo("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" . $document->path);
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/file-response-from-s3

Answer (score 0):

```
       $d = image full path here..
       $d = str_replace(' ', '%20', $d);   //remove the whitespace in url
       ob_end_clean();
       header("Cache-Control: public");
       header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $d);              
       header("Content-Type: image/png");


       return readfile($d);
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks